# DETAIL: Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 1073741429 bytes by 412 more bytes

Tags: python, psycopg2

Getting error about 1GB buffer limit while running consume function in python.

I want to read WALs from a Postgres server using consume function with wal2json plugin. But getting Out of memory after buffer size reaches 1GB. I tried to reset the start point of WAL reading using send_feedback function but still getting this error.

Main function has code snippet like this:-

```
    connect_string="dbname='" + dbname + "' host='" + host + "' user='" + user + "'"
    my_connection  = psycopg2.connect(connect_string , connection_factory = LogicalReplicationConnection)
    cur = my_connection.cursor()
    cur.drop_replication_slot('postgres2')
    cur.create_replication_slot('postgres2', output_plugin = 'wal2json')
    cur.start_replication(slot_name = 'postgres2', options = {'pretty-print' : 1,'include-xids' : 1,'include-timestamp' : 1}, decode= True)
    cur.consume_stream(consume)
```

Consume function is like this:-

```
    def consume(msg):
      trx_dict = json.loads(msg.payload)
      .....
      something with this trx_dict variable
      .....
      print("WAL end position: " +str(msg.wal_end))
      msg.cursor.send_feedback(write_lsn=msg.wal_end,apply_lsn=msg.wal_end,force=True)
```

Output of this code is like:-

```
WAL end position: 155031288079488
WAL end position: 155031288081016
WAL end position: 155031290703248
WAL end position: 155031291360928
WAL end position: 155031298594232
WAL end position: 155048500184480
WAL end position: 155048501852048
WAL end position: 155048502483744
WAL end position: 155048502495360
WAL end position: 155048503041176
WAL end position: 155048663445952
WAL end position: 155049542590544
WAL end position: 155050592835120
WAL end position: 155052409327592
WAL end position: 155063749581032
WAL end position: 155064127938992
WAL end position: 155065834545224
WAL end position: 155078845385720
WAL end position: 155083517986984
out of memory
DETAIL:  Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 1073741429 bytes by 412 more bytes.
CONTEXT:  slot "postgres2", output plugin "wal2json", in the change callback, associated LSN 8D04/B4B5CF18
```

I tried to reset the start point of WAL reading using flush_lsn, write_lsn and apply_lsn parameter in send_feedback function. Ref link: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html but still buffer limit reached of 1GB. Is there a way reset buffer to point where I have read the WALs or increase the buffer size of 1GB?

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit build of Python?

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: We are facing the same issue. Any design tips or workarounds for this when dealing with many changes? We are using the the v2 of the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

That log message format (`DETAIL:` ... `CONTEXT:`) indicates it comes from PostgreSQL, not Python.

PostgreSQL has an internal limit on allocations of 1 GB, among others visible in the limit of 1 GB on binary blobs and text field sizes (documented here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/limits.html) and I suspect that's the limit you're hitting (or something related to it).

It would have happened in any environment, not just Python. I think you need to find a way to process less data on the PostgreSQL side. Don't know how, though.

Comment: We don't have any binary blob field in the DB which I have been listening to. This behaviour is very random. Sometimes it occur after 20-24 hours and sometimes within 1 hour. I suspect it depends on the number of transactions occurring during that window. If large number of transactions are occurring then buffer limit get hit very quickly.